# Data Listing According to Column From Table 1 to Table 2 in 2 Different SQL Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 2 different sql tables.

1.Table name: lottery

2.Table name: lottery_participant

1.Table (lottery), 2.Table "id" of table "lottery" (lottery_participant) 2. The table "lottery_id" depends on. As it appears in the picture.

[image]

What I want to do is I want to pull the data that has reached the number of data in the "lottery_participant" table based on the "max" value in the "lottery" table.

**My SQL Code. (INCORRECT)**

```
SELECT *,
CASE
    WHEN COUNT(P.id) >= L.max THEN NULL
END AS 'KISA AD' 
FROM lottery as L
INNER JOIN lottery_participant as P 
ON 
L.id = P.lottery_id
WHERE L.status= '0'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want lotteries that are at or above the max:

```
SELECT l.*, lp.cnt
FROM lottery L JOIN
     (SELECT lp.lottery_id, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM lottery_participant lp
      GROUP BY lp.lottery_id
     ) lp
     ON l.id = lp.lottery_id
WHERE L.status = 0 AND cnt >= l.max
```

Comment: Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'lp.lottery_id' in 'field list'